# Is it possible to know what actions have been called on an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I have several conditions that might affect what filters (`.Where(...)`) are  used on a list. And at some point an exception is thrown, and I would like to know what actions have been called upon the list up until this point.

Is something like this possible?

```
var myList = new List<SomeClass>();

myList = myList.Where(item => item.property == value);
.
.
.
myList = myList.Where(item => item.otherProperty < otherValue);

Console.WriteLine(myList.ToActionsString());
```

It might print something like this:

```
list.Where(i => i.property == <the actual value>)
    .Where(i => i.otherProperty < <the actual otherValue>)
```

Just calling `toString()` on the list does not exactly give any relevant information, and just listing the items in the list is not of interest.

Comment: enable "break when thrown" within VS-->Debug-->Window-->Exception Settings. Shows you pretty exactly where an exception occurs.

Comment: This seems like you are trying to save your self work by creating your self more work. Why not just log the inputs to the conditions with a message of what condition it was for

Comment: *what actions have been called upon the list up until this point* LINQ doesn't really work that way. The delegates are applied to the lists item by item. So your first Where clause is applied to the first item, then the second Where clause... then both Where clauses are applied to the second item... etc. This is referred to as deferred execution. You can't log anything that describes how the list has been filtered so far because the list isn't filtered step by step in the order that your code appears. Not unless you call `ToList()` in between each clause.

Comment: On top of that, the new list has no memory of where it came from - what is being asked here is essentially some sort of audit trail. Nice idea. TOTALLY useless in 99.9999% of the cases (i.e. noone ever case in most use cases) but it would use a TON of money in all those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Warning**: there is overhead to this as the compiler has to create all of the `Expression` objects (which then have to be allocated and compiled at runtime). *Use this sparingly*.

You can do this using `AsQueryable` and relying on the `ToString` logic of the built in `EnumerableQuery` and `Expression` classes. The following extension method will convert your query to it's textual representation:

```
public static string GetText<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) {
   retury query.Expression.ToString();
}
```

It can be used like:

```
var list = new List<int>();
var query = list.AsQueryable()
                .Select((c, i) => c * (i + 1))
                .Where(c => c > 5)
                .Where(c => c < 10 && c != 7)
                .Take(2)
                .OrderBy(x => 1);   
var text = query.GetText();
```

This results in the following:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32].Select((c, i) => (c * (i + 1))).Where(c => (c > 5)).Where(c => ((c < 10) AndAlso (c != 7))).Take(2).OrderBy(x => 1)
```

We can throw an anonymous type in the mix just to see how it looks:

```
var query = list.AsQueryable()
                .Select((c, i) => c * (i + 1))
                .Select(x => new { Value = x, ValueSquared = x * x });
var result = query.GetText();
```

Which will print:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32].Select((c, i) => (c * (i + 1))).Select(x => new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(Value = x, ValueSquared = (x * x)))
```

Through the use of `Expression` manipulation, we can make this method a little bit more robust. We can add in line breaks between the method calls and optionally strip off the name of the list's type.

```
public static string GetText<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, bool lineBreaks, bool noClassName)
{
    var text = query.Expression.ToString();

    if (!lineBreaks && !noClassName) 
        return text;

    var expression = StripQuotes(query.Expression);
    if (!(expression is MethodCallExpression mce)) 
        return text;

    if (lineBreaks)
    {
        var strings = new Stack<string>();
        strings.Push(mce.ToString());

        while (mce.Arguments.Count > 0 && mce.Arguments[0] is MethodCallExpression me)
        {
            strings.Push(me.ToString());
            mce = me;
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder(strings.Pop());

        var len = sb.Length;
        while (strings.TryPop(out var item))
        {
            sb.AppendLine().Append(item.Substring(len));
            len = item.Length;
        }    
        text = sb.ToString();
    }

    if (mce.Arguments.Count > 0 && mce.Arguments[0] is ConstantExpression ce)
    {
        var root = ce.Value.ToString();
        if (root != null && text.StartsWith(root))
        {
            text = noClassName
                    ? text.Substring(root.Length + 1)
                    : text.Insert(root.Length, Environment.NewLine);
        }        
    }

    return text;
}

// helper in case we get an actual Queryable in there
private static Expression StripQuotes(Expression e) 
{
    while (e.NodeType == ExpressionType.Quote)
        e = ((UnaryExpression)e).Operand;
    return e;
}
```

We can call this method as follows:

```
var list = new List<int>();
var query = list.AsQueryable()
                .Select((c, i) => c * (i + 1))
                .Where(c => c > 5)
                .Where(c => c < 10 && c != 7)
                .Take(2)
                .OrderBy(x => 1);   
var text = query.GetText(true, true);
```

Which will produce the following:

```
Select((c, i) => (c * (i + 1)))
.Where(c => (c > 5))
.Where(c => ((c < 10) AndAlso (c != 7)))
.Take(2)
.OrderBy(x => 1)
```

Note that this is very basic. It's not going to cover the case of closures (passing variables in) you'll get the `<>DisplayClass` objects written into your query. We can resolve that with an `ExpressionVisitor` that walks the expression and evaluates the `ConstantExpression`s representing the closures.

(Unfortunately I do not have time at the moment to provide that `ExpressionVisitor` solution, but stay tuned for an update)

Comment: I'll try and post an update today with a really robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, at least not in a direct way as described in your question.

The `List` is not filtered step by step (i.e., apply `Where(expr1)` for all elements, then `Where(expr2)` for all remaining elements, ...), but in a deferred way:

1. If you request the first item of the resulting `IEnumerable`, LINQ evaluates the `expr1` clause for each item until one item matches.
2. Then it checks whether this list item also matches `expr2`.
3. - If it does, return it (or pass to further `Where` stages).
   - If it doesn't match, go back to step 1 and continue finding an item which matches `expr1`.

So logging by simply calling some `ToActionsString()` is difficult here. As already noted in the comments, it is probably much easier to just log when adding the `Where`-clauses, since you are in a known state then anyway:

```
if(condition1)
{
    myList = myList.Where(item => item.Property == value);
    Log($"Adding expression 1 with value '{value}'");
}
```

---

If your concern is that `value` could change before the `IEnumerable` is actually *evaluated* (captured variable), and you cannot restructure your control flow adequately, a workaround may be to create `Func<T>` objects which output the captured variables, and to evaluate those immediately before iterating the list:

```
List<Func<int>> values = new List<Func<int>>();
if(condition1)
{
    myList = myList.Where(item => item.Property == value);
    values.Add(() => value);
}
...
foreach(var v in values)
    Log($"List will be filtered by {v()}");
var filteredList = myList.ToList();
```

---

Finally, you could call some logging function in your expressions, which logs the conditions and/or catches exceptions when evaluating those conditions:

```
myList.Where(item => 
{
    Log(item, value);
    return item.Property == value;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was afraid that this was not possible, but your answer gave me a lot of clarity in the way LINQ evaluates items.

Comment: You could use AsQueryable and then construct your Where clauses over the queryable which will create an expression tree. After that you could use an expression visitor to print out the calls to the query. Finally ToList (or whatever you use to materialize) will itself use the underlying expressions to get the result. The built in linq to objects query provider will translate to the correct result. Though there's  some overhead to this

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Not shure about the ExpressionVisitor, but the part about using AsQueryable to create an expression tree might just have solved this, because when just printing the Queryable.Expression, I get more or less the output I want (except for the actual value we are checking against). Created a fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mdt2Ti showing this in action.